# How can I download a whole web page in Python using pywebcopy when I also need a login?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I used `pywebcopy` to download the entire web page and it worked like a charm. However I need to do it on a site where I am a member. How can I type in login credentials into `pywebcopy`?

The code that I used is as in `pywebcopy` example:

```
from pywebcopy import save_webpage

url = 'http://some-site.com/some-page.html'
download_folder = '/path/to/downloads/'    

kwargs = {'bypass_robots': True, 'project_name': 'recognisable-name'}

save_webpage(url, download_folder, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I suggest using the requests library instead

Answer (score 0):

Try to find API request url while you logging in to website you need. It must give cookies back to you. You need save them, and send them when you download the page

Comment: Ok, and they would do that how?